# Теорема о разделяющих осях

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, mouse-event

Здравствуйте, сделал столкновение двух правильных многоугольников с помощью теоремы о разделяющих осях. может подскажет кто, как переделать на множество фигур, так как возник вопрос как отслеживать с какой фигурой я хочу столкнуть выбранную фигуру?

```js
function Shape(points, x, y, color, stroke) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.points = points.map(function (el) {
        return {x: el[0], y: el[1]};
    });
    this.color = color || "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
    this.stroke = stroke || "black";
    this.getNormals();
    this.getMedians();
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    var p = this.points;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
    p.forEach(function (point, i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        } else if (i === (p.length - 1)) {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p[0].x, p[0].y);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    });
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
};

Shape.prototype.getNormals = function () {
    var p = this.points,
        n = p.length,
        crt, nxt, l, x1, y1;

    this.normals = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        crt = p[i];
        nxt = p[i + 1] || p[0];
        x1 = (nxt.y - crt.y);
        y1 = -(nxt.x - crt.x);
        l = Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
        this.normals[i] = {x: x1 / l, y: y1 / l};
        this.normals[n + i] = {x: - x1 / l, y: - y1 / l};
    }
};

Shape.prototype.getMedians = function () {
    var p = this.points,
        crt, nxt;

    this.medians = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        crt = p[i];
        nxt = p[i + 1] || p[0];
        this.medians.push({x: (crt.x + nxt.x) / 2, y: (crt.y + nxt.y) / 2});
    }
};

Shape.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Shape.prototype.checkCollision = function (shape) {
    var me = this,
        p1, p2;

    return me.normals.concat(shape.normals).every(function (v) {
        p1 = me.project(v);
        p2 = shape.project(v);

        return (((p1.min <= p2.max) && (p1.max >= p2.min)) ||
        (p2.min >= p1.max) && (p2.max >= p1.min));
    });
};

Shape.prototype.project = function (vector) {
    var me = this,
        p = this.points,
        min = Infinity, max = -Infinity,
        x, y, proj;

    p.forEach(function (p) {
        x = me.x + p.x;
        y = me.y + p.y;
        proj = (x * vector.x + y * vector.y);
        min = proj < min ? proj : min;
        max = proj > max ? proj : max;
    });

    return {min: min, max: max};
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("scene"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    w = window.innerWidth,
    h = window.innerHeight,
    isDown = false,
    list = {
        triangle: new Shape([[30, 0], [60, 60], [0, 60]], 50, 50),
        rhombus: new Shape([[50, 0], [100, 50], [50, 100], [0, 50]], 200, 50)
    },
    render = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        for (var shape in list) {
            if (list.hasOwnProperty(shape)) {
                list[shape].draw(ctx);
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    isDown = true;
    checkFigures({x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY});
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    isDown = false;
    for (var figure in list) {
        list[figure].moving = false;
    }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    var fig;
    if (isDown) {
        for (var figure in list) {
            fig = list[figure];
            if (fig.moving) {
                fig.move(e.clientX - fig.delta.x, e.clientY - fig.delta.y);
                if (list.triangle.checkCollision(list.rhombus)) {
                    list.triangle.stroke = 'red';
                    list.rhombus.stroke = 'red';
                } else {
                    list.triangle.stroke = 'black';
                    list.rhombus.stroke = 'black';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

function checkFigures(mp) {
    for (var fig in list) {
        if (isPointInPoly(list[fig].points, {x: mp.x - list[fig].x, y: mp.y - list[fig].y})) {
            list[fig].moving = true;
            list[fig].delta = {
                x: mp.x - list[fig].x,
                y: mp.y - list[fig].y
            };
        }
    }
}

function isPointInPoly(poly, pt) {
    for (var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
        ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y))
        && (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x)
        && (c = !c);
    return c;
}

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="scene"></canvas>
    <script src="Shape.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```